# Using Apache Cordova/PhoneGap with Android 2.x

Tags: android, cordova

It seems that it isn't possible to create a PhoneGap app for Android 2.x.  Is that right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For running android applications using phonegap build your application as Android 4.0.3 and set the minimum version to the lower version whatever you want. Basically Android 4.0.3 build does not affect the functionalities of the older android version. And this app perfectly works with android lower versions.

I usually do like this in manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay - so answering my own question.  You need Android API mark 15 installed for PhoneGap to work.

But . . . you can change the AndroidManifest.xml file in the application to make it backwards compatible.

For example

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

will be compatible with 2.3.3

Comment: Yes, PhoneGap will work from SDK 7 (Android 2.1) up to SDK 15 (4.0.3). I always recommend that people build their app with the latest SDK but set a min SDK version that they want their app to run on.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald +1 for letting us know what the min/max supported version is.

Comment: Well we support SDK 16 now as well.