# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK in phonegap adb

Tags: android, cordova, adb

I'm trying to install an app into my device. I type phonegap local build android and compiles just fine.Then I type phonegap run android and I get the following nice reply in the terminal:

```
syd@whitebook:~/Desktop/testapp$ phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] successfully installed onto device
```

But no application can be found in my mobile(Debug enabled & Unknow sources allowed).
Then I navigate to platforms/android/bin and do this: adb install SomeTest-debug.apk
and I get the error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK.

Mobile: HTC Wildfire with android version: 2.2.1

And here is my config.xml in the www folder:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.tech.testapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>SomeTest</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
</widget>
```

As you see miSDK is version 8 which is Android 2.2 if I'm not mistaken.
Could someone please tell me why is this happening and what is the issue here that prevents me from getting the app to work on my mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the problem is with the `min-target-sdk` version. I think that the 8 which you specify in the config.xml is being overwritten by Cordova/Phonegap CLI. What is the value of `min-target-sdk` when you look in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of the app itself, after it is compiled? When I look at mine, it is always '10', which is Android 2.3.3. Since this is the min supported SDK, this is the reason adb is unable to install on your emulator. Bump your emulator SDK up to API 10 and it should work.

Cordova currently only supports Android 2.3 and above, see https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/8d8cbf6e284bc67c4e8502a6238c83d2645b815e

Comment: I will test it now. But I suppose that I wont be able to test it in my phone because it has android 2.2.3. Am I correct? So only emulator...

Comment: Right, correct, if your phone is only 2.2 (API 8), you won't be able to install apps targeted for 2.3.3 (API 10).

Comment: You are correct however on the link that you shared has minsdk version of 8

Comment: Hmmm  you're right, I didn't notice that at first. What are you seeing in the `AndroidManifest` of the build application? Does it say min is 8 or 10? I just built a new app with 3.0 and it sets the min-sdk to 10...somehow...hmm..

Comment: Yes it sets minSDK to 10 however take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058816/using-apache-cordova-phonegap-with-android-2-x

Comment: I changed minSDK in my manifest file and now I'm able to test the application to my mobile device as well. It seems that you can alter thet minsdk value without major issues I suppose

Comment: I'd make sure that you test pretty thoroughly on the lower level. Usually the Cordova team bumped the min-sdk level when they start using new Android API's that may not be supported. If it is working, probably you are not using any of the 'new' functionality (which is fine.) I'm still curious as to why the min SDK gets set to 10 even though it says 8 in the code above...I wonder if it just builds for the lowest AVD installed on your machine or something. I'm trying to create a test app manually without the CLI to see if there is a difference...

Comment: Well I had installed lower AVDS than 10. In case you resolve this post  a comment here. I'd be interested in this & thnx again.

Answer (score 0):

first uninstall same pkg name application from device.
then re install.